# Circular permutation about pair

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Some six of people are men, and the other six are women. In how many ways can they join hands for a circle dance, assuming they alternate in gender around the circle?

Comment: Alicia is the dance leader. The other women can be arranged in $5!$ orders with respect to Alicia, and for each such arrangement the men can be arranged in $6!$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it like this:

First you pick the places for the women.

The number of ways to arrange
$n$ distinct objects in a circle
is $(n-1)!$ and not $n!$.

This is because the circle can be rotated.

If you rotate the circle with the 
six women you notice there 
are only $5!$ distinguishable ways they
can be placed in the circle.

If you take the simpler scenario with
only three people in a circle you get

$123:$ $1$st arrangement

$132:$ $2$nd arrangement

$213:$ $2$nd arrangement rotated clockwise one turn

$231:$ $1$st arrangement rotated clockwise two turns

$312:$ $1$st arrangement rotated clockwise one turn

$321:$ $2$nd arrangement rotated clockwise two turns

Here the first digit is placed
in the top spot and the other
two going clockwise around the circle.

Then when you have picked the places
for the women you start to fill
in each gap between two women with a man.

In the first gap you can choose between
$6$ men, then $5$ and so on, i.e. there
are $6!$ ways arrange the men.

This give a total of $5!*6!$ ways they can join hands for a circle dance.